# Bash / Django : Run a several watch commands in one shell, each with separate environment variables

Tags: python, django, bash, terminal

I have a Django set up for which I need to run a command every two seconds. The command looks like this:

```
watch SITE=<site_name> ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

I set the `SITE` as the VM environment variable, which is then used by the Django system to know which site it needs to run that command against, as well as other things. All of the "sites" run from the same codebase and it runs within a virtual environment.

The problem is that now there are 7 "sites" that I need to run this command against every two seconds and there are more in the pipeline. This means that I have seven Terminal tabs open, each running the same VM separately and each running that command every two seconds!

Is there a way that I can perhaps have some kind of script so that these commands are run for each site in the same way, but in one Terminal tab? Or even better, just running in the background?

Comment: I'm not sure the question is appropriate. There is no answer that can be given that will 'answer it'. That said, take a look at 'foreman'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because watch can't be run in the background, a simple script will accomplish what you're looking for.  Using a for loop should make it simple to increase the amount of sites.  if you run watch on the script then you can continue to get your repetitive execution.

Something else to look at would be [cron](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) if you can relax your requirement to once a minute.

```
#!/bin/bash
for SITE_NAME in <site1> <site2> <site3>
do
    SITE=$SITE_NAME ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput
done
```

Comment: Thank you Voider this is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about what you're wanting.
This is a general purpose bash script to run some commands in the background each 2 seconds:

```
#!/bin/bash

command1 &
command2 &
command3 &

#wait
# decomment the line above if you want to wait until
# all the spawned process ends before going further

sleep 2
exec $0
```

The script itself could be run in background by calling it with a pending ampersand:

```
./script.sh &
```